# how to change negative number in array to their index slot

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, counter

Im trying to change the negative numbers in the wholeNumbers array to their slot/index-number and then print out the array. Also I have to use a while loop. This is what Ive got so far, but now Im stuck. Am I on the right track copying the array? How do I proceed, is it correct that "change[counter]" be equal to "counter"? Or am my thinking wrong? When i run i get error

```
public class NegativeNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] wholeNumbers = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
    int counter = 0;
    int negativeCounter = 0;
    int sum = 0;

 while(counter < wholeNumbers.length) {
   if(wholeNumbers[counter] < 0)
   {
     sum += wholeNumbers[counter];
     negativeCounter++;
   }
  counter++;

  }
System.out.println("Negative numbers: "+negativeCounter);


int[] change = Arrays.copyOf(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length);

while(counter < change.length) { //get error
  if(change[counter] < 0){
     change[counter]=counter;
System.out.println(change[counter]);
  }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: The original task was to use this array: int[] wholeNumbers = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2}; and make a program that counts the negative numbers. Then Im supposed to change the negative numbers to their slot number and print out.

Comment: Ive edited my original post, tried to run, but get error

Comment: You're not incrementing your counter in your second while loop

Comment: Should the counter be inside and outside the loop? The error I get is : cannot find symbol and it points to the :"Arrays.copyOf(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length);"    This is the code:                                                                    int[] change = Arrays.copyOf(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length);
  while(counter < wholeNumbers.length) {
    if(change[counter] < 0){
      change[counter]=counter;
      counter++;
    }
      counter++;

    System.out.println(change[counter]);
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] wholeNumbers = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};

    int negativeCount;

    for(int i = 0; i < wholeNumbers.length; i++) {
        if(wholeNumbers[i] < 0) {
            negativeCount++;

            wholeNumbers[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

With a `while`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] wholeNumbers = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};

    int negativeCount;

    int idx = 0;

    while(idx < wholeNumbers.length) {
        if(wholeNumbers[idx] < 0) {
            negativeCount++;

            wholeNumbers[idx] = idx;
        }

        idx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you:) the two tasks are supposed to be in the same program, when I run with your code I get error: "wholeNumbers is already defined in method main". How do I solve this? When i try the : "int[] change = Arrays.copyOf(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length);", I get error "can not find symbol". Is it supposed to be outside main?

Comment: I don't know, maybe don't define the same variable twice? I gave you a whole working example, take out the parts you need/don't need.

Answer (score 0):

here is it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NegativeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] wholeNumbers = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
        int counter = 0;
        int negativeCounter = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while(counter < wholeNumbers.length) 
        {
            if(wholeNumbers[counter] < 0)
            {
                sum += wholeNumbers[counter];
                negativeCounter++;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: "+negativeCounter);

        int[] change = Arrays.copyOf(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length);
        counter = 0; // You forgot to reset this
        while(counter < change.length) 
        {
            if(change[counter] < 0)
            {
                change[counter]=counter;
                System.out.println(change[counter]);
            }
            counter++; // You forgot to increment this
        }// while
   }// main
}
```

There were two errors, the counter variable needed to be set back to zero, and into the second while you needed to increment it again (see the comments inside the code).

The output of your program now is:

```
Negative numbers: 3
3
4
8
```